# PowerShell ISE: disable/remove Module Browser

Tags: powershell

PowerShell ISE version 5.1.17763.1432, Windows 10 Enterprise build 1809.

How do I disable/remove the 'Module Browser' add-in that keeps trying to start up & show on the **right**-hand side of the ISE? I don't need it, I won't use it, and it's usually broken anyway.

I tried Googling for this, and all the results were articles/posts about how to use/enable it, not how to remove/disable it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the 'Commands' tab?

It's not called the module browser. Though there is an AddOn for that as there is on for scripts, projects, etc. Just see the AddOn menu for the website.

You cannot remove this addon, you can set it not to show...

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.VerticalAddOnTools

Name     IsVisible Control                                                          
----     --------- -------                                                          
Commands      True Microsoft.Windows.PowerShell.Gui.Internal.ShowCommandAddOnControl
```

...but that does not mean it's not there.

Sure, it has a drop-down for modules, as a filter, but it is no different than typing...

```
Show-Command # get all command just like the addon.
```

or

```
Show-Command -Name Get-ChildItem # get the target command only
```

... directly. So, if you do the above, it's the same thing as double-clicking that command in that tab. BTW, there is no Show-Module cmdlet to do the same thing.

The addon only loads to the right, not on the left, and the setting for whether it loads/displays or not is in the 'AddOns menu', and on the toolbar.

Close it with the 'x' in the GUI, just uncheck in the AddOns menu, and restart the ISE and it will not display, or put code in your $profile that unchecks it on load.

***The ISE has a programmable object model. See the links provided***

What you need to understand, is that it is not just a display thing, it tells you whether a module or cmdlet or function is available. If you do an implicit PSRemote session, say to Exchange, AD, SQL, to proxy those cmdlets to your host, you will not have those cmdlets available until you hit the refresh button on the addon for the session to load them.

So, whether you click on anything to lookup stuff there, it is being used. FYI, the moment you move to VSCode, it has one of these as well, because people asked for it, though it does not suffer from the need to click Refresh on implicit remote sessions like the ISE, it has its own annoying quirks and issues. All tools do.

You say you looked, but [I am surprised you did not find this:](https://gist.github.com/darrenjrobinson/100c5c94be1bb581fea50ad643f19a0c)

```
# Remove ISE AddOn
# list ISE Vertical AddOn Tools
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.VerticalAddOnTools

# Add on name from the list retreived above
$addOnName = 'PowerGist'

# Check you've spelled it right and remove
$exists = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.VerticalAddOnTools | where { $_.Name -eq $addOnName }
if ($exists) {
    $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.VerticalAddOnTools.Remove($exists)
}

# verify its gone
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.VerticalAddOnTools
```

The above will allow you to remove all other addons except the 'Commands Tab' as it's part of the ISE, and since no more work is going into the ISE, it's there forever.

***ISE Tech References:***

> • PowerShell ISE (built-in Editor)
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/exploring-the-windows-powershell-ise
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell_ise
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/exploring-the-windows-powershell-ise
>
> ```
> Using PowerShell 7 in the Windows PowerShell ISE
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLolNWuICoM&feature=emb_rel_end
> ```
>
> • Purpose of the Windows PowerShell ISE Scripting Object Model
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/purpose-of-the-windows-powershell-ise-scripting-object-model
>
> • The ISE Object Model Hierarchy - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-ise-object-model-hierarchy
>
> • The ObjectModelRoot Object - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-objectmodelroot-object
>
> • The ISEOptions Object - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs
> The ISEOptions object represents various settings for Windows PowerShell ISE.
> It is an instance of the Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions class.
>
> • The ISEOptions object provides the following methods and properties.
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-iseoptions-object
>
> • The ISEAddOnTool Object - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/object-model/the-iseaddontool-object
>
> • Adding Exchange Shell items to PowerShell ISE
> https://eightwone.com/2012/10/25/adding-exchange-shell-items-to-powershell-ise
>
> • An Overview of the PowerShell ISE Object Model
> https://www.petri.com/overview-powershell-ise-object-model
>
> • Using the PowerShell ISE Editor Object - Petri
> https://www.petri.com/using-powershell-ise-editor-object
>
> • Using the AddOnsMenu property in the PowerShell ISE
> https://www.petri.com/using-addonsmenu-property-powershell-ise-object-model
>
> • Windows PowerShell ISE Object Model Reference
> https://forsenergy.com/en-us/windowspowershellhelp/html/e1a9e7d1-0fd5-47de-8d9b-f1be1ed13b0c.htm
>
> • The ISEFile Object
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/object-model/the-isefile-object?view=powershell-7
>
> • The PowerShellTab Object
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/object-model/the-powershelltab-object?view=powershell-7

***Update***

So, that module browser is something that you or someone had to download and install on your system from here:

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45885

Or you or they did this.

```
Find-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon -Force
Install-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon -Force
```

That is not the builtin Commands Tab, though it does get added to that part of the ISE UI. It's not part of the ISE AddOns by default. That one really does not work well anymore, neither does the ScriptBrowser, ProjectExplorer, etc. You just need to uninstall those. Delete the module from your Modules folder, and any calls to it in your profile.

```
Import-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon
```

... and in PowerShell, do this...

```
Uninstall-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon -Force
```

Comment: Wow! Incredibly in-depth, thorough answer. But.. and forgive me if I'm being naive.. are we talking about the same thing? [Here is a picture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avsj1PUMbksi-EFP98aruEY-WE0B) of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Edited question to clarify - this shows up on the right-hand side of the ISE, not the left. Apologies.

Comment: No worries. See my update for you based you your comment here.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. FYI / for future readers, I found [this article](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/powershell-profile-location/) particularly helpful in telling you how to find your PoSh profiles so you can purge them of junk imports/modules. =)

Comment: This is well documented in the PowerShell help files as well. By default any module you install yourself is always to your own profile path. When you install a module, PowerShell gives you two options. [Install-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon -Scope CurrentUser] or [Install-Module -Name ISEModuleBrowserAddon -Scope AllUsers]. In 99.999% of the case, these two are the only ones you'd need to worry about.